# Improving the speed of a continuous to discrete operator

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I have defined an integral operator `hm[func_, m_, n_]` that discretizes a continuous 2D function into its pixel counterpart where `Dm[x_,y_,m_,n_]` is the kernel of the operator. This kernel uses Mathematica's 2D `UnitBox` function.

Definition of the operator:

```
Dm[x_,y_,m_,n_] := 1/(PixelWidth)^2 UnitBox[(x - m*PixelPitch /2)/PixelWidth, 
                   (y - n*PixelPitch /2)/PixelWidth] /.{PixelWidth-> 1.2, PixelPitch -> 1.5};  

hm[func_,m_,n_] := NIntegrate[Dm[x, y, m, n] func, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
                              {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 10, 
                              PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10];
```

I define an example function that becomes the input to `hm[func_,m_,n_]`:

```
ExampleFunc[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2/2 + y^2/2)];
```

Here I define the pixel coordinates and generate the output, i.e. the discretized function, using `hm[func_,m_,n_]`:

```
NumberOfPixelsX = 6;    
NumberOfPixelsY = 10; 

AllPixelCords = Table[{i, j}, {i, NumberOfPixelsY/2, -NumberOfPixelsY/2, -1}, {j, NumberOfPixelsX/2, -NumberOfPixelsX/2, -1}];
FlattenedAllPixelCords = Flatten[AllPixelCords, {1, 2}];

PixelCoordinates = DeleteCases[DeleteCases[FlattenedAllPixelCords, {_, 0}, Infinity], {0, _}, Infinity];  (* Remove pixel coordinates with 0's*)

OperatorResult = hm[ExampleFunc[x, y], PixelCoordinates[[All, 1]], PixelCoordinates[[All, 2]]];

DiscretizedFunction = Partition[OperatorResult, NumberOfPixelsX];
MatrixPlot[DiscretizedFunction]
```

My problem is that this operation takes a lot of time to complete when I increase the number of pixels, i.e. when I use greater values for `NumberOfPixelsX` and `NumberOfPixelsY`. Is there a way to speed this up?.

Comment: What is the resolution you are aiming for? I.e. how large would you like `NumberOfPixelsX/Y` to be?

Comment: Another question: are you interested in this kernel specifically, for various functions, or do we also need to keep the kernel general?

Comment: I would like to use `NumberOfPixelsX = 512`  and `NumberOfPixelsY = 1024`. I am interested in this kernel because I need its value to be 1 for a specific pixel coordinate (`PixelCoordinates`) and 0 for all the other coordinates. You can plot `Plot3D[Dm[x,y,1,1]ExampleFunc[x, y], {x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]` to see what `Dm` is doing and then I integrate over that area. I want to keep the kernel general because I want to apply a different functions to it.

Comment: Then you should change the limits of the integration instead. The integration is what's currently taking a lot of time

Comment: I can keep the limits as `{x,-256,256`} and `{y,-512,512}` but even that takes too long. Is there any other way to change it over different pixel coordinates (`PixelCoordinates`)?.

Comment: Make the integration limits depend on m and n in hm[...]

Comment: If the kernel is sufficiently smooth and the window for each pixel is sufficiently small, then a $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ Gauss quadrature for each pixel would do the job...

Comment: Expanding on what @HenrikSchumacher writes, the default behavior of `NIntegrate` is to use Global Adaptive sampling with an integration rule that is chosen by analyzing the symbolic form of the integrand... This takes some time. So we need to make each call to `NIntegrate` as simple as possible.

Comment: `WorkingPrecision->10` together with `PrecisionGoal->10` is wrong. Use machine precision or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping `Nintegrate`, performing $3 \times 3$ Gauss quadrature by hand, and compiling everything into a neat, listable, and parallelized `CompiledFunction`:

```
ExampleFunc[x_, y_] := Exp[-0.5 (x^2 + y^2)];

Block[{dx, dy, gausspts, gaussweights, weights},

 {gausspts, gaussweights} = Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[3, $MachinePrecision]];
 weights = Flatten[KroneckerProduct[gaussweightsx, gaussweightsy]];

 cdiscretize = With[{code = Dot[
      Flatten[
       Outer[
        ExampleFunc,
        Compile`GetElement[P, 1] + dx gausspts,
        Compile`GetElement[P, 2] + dy gausspts
        ]
       ],
      Flatten[KroneckerProduct[gaussweights, gaussweights]]
      ]},
   Compile[{{P, _Real, 1}, {dx, _Real}, {dy, _Real}},
    code,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
 ]
```

Now lets apply this function:

```
{NumberOfPixelsX, NumberOfPixelsY} = {512, 1024};
{xmin, xmax} = {-1., 1.};
{ymin, ymax} = {-2., 2.};
Δx = (xmax - xmin)/NumberOfPixelsX;
Δy = (ymax - ymin)/NumberOfPixelsY;
lowerx = Most[Subdivide[xmin, xmax, NumberOfPixelsX]];
lowery = Most[Subdivide[ymin, ymax, NumberOfPixelsY]];
lowerleftcorners = Flatten[Outer[List, lowerx, lowery], 1]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

discretizedFunction = Partition[
     cdiscretize[lowerleftcorners, Δx, Δy],
     NumberOfPixelsY
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

ArrayPlot[discretizedFunction]
```

> 0.005842
>
> 0.02524

[image]

As a sanity check, we can compare to the values of the function `ExampleFunc` sampled on the pixel centers (this is equivalent to using $1 \times 1$ Gauss quadrature per pizel):

```
sampledFunction = Outer[ExampleFunc, lowerx + 0.5 Δx, lowery + 0.5 Δy];
Max[Abs[discretizedFunction - sampledFunction]]
```

> 1.27155*10^-6

Thus, the error introduced by using a $3 \times 3$ Gauss quadrature might be way below machine precision.

Comment: Your code is really fast but can I use nested `NIntegrate` in your code?. For example, let `ExampleFunc[x_, y_] := NIntegrate[Exp[-0.5 (x^2 + y^2)] Exp[p], {p, -5, 5}];`. I intend to discretize a very big function that results from a numerical integration that cannot be done using symbolic integration.

Comment: In principle, you can add more dimensions to integrate over with `Outer` and `KroneckerProduct`. `NIntegrate` intself cannot be compiled, so the compiled approach would not work (it would be very slow due to callbacks to Mathematica's main evaluator). But every further dimension will make it more and more costly so that one would have to focus much more on specific properies of the problem at hand.

Comment: For example, `Exp[-0.5 (x^2 + y^2)] Exp[p]Exp[-0.5 (x^2 + y^2)] Exp[p]` can be written as product `Exp[-0.5 x^2] Exp[-0.5 y^2] Exp[p]` so that one can integrate it over `x`, `y`, and `p` _independently of each other_.

Comment: Thanks, I sure first have to understand how to implement Gaussian quadrature in higher dimensions. It is certainly a better approach than `NIntegrage`. Anyways, I tried a workaround `hm[func_, m_, n_] := NIntegrate[Dm[xout, yout, m, n] func, {xout, m*0.048046875/2 - 0.048/2, m*0.048046875/2 + 0.048/2}, {yout, n*0.048046875/2 - 0.048/2, n*0.048046875/2 + 0.048/2}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];`. If I apply the `ExampleFunc` to this, it gives result a little faster and the results seem correct as well. What do you think about this?.

Comment: `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0` is a very good idea. You can also try using `Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 3}, MaxRecursion -> 0` as options for `NIntegrate`.